# How to have one core in several applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, architecture

My objective is developing several apps using the same core (code) just have different UI (color, asset's, etc.).

I don't know if I can compare to MVC but I want to reuse the *Model* and *Controller* having several *Views*

**Important:**

- Can be only one project?

  - For example creating different target or other configuration project..
- If I discover a bug I want resolve just once.
- Generating separated build's.

  - The bundle have only the resources that I want (new target right?)

I saw several apps using this (theoretically) like sports apps (soccer, etc).

Thanks

**Edit**** More detail

[image]

Comment: You can create a static library or a framework which contains your common code (not just functional code, but also UI like commonly used custom views, etc). Use this lib or framework in other projects.

Comment: hum is true thanks, but if I want to have only one project? and also if I discover a bug I will resolve once and copy again the lib/framework to the others projects?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to use this : http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial
The Core can be a project, in which you're going to define the common classes. These common classes may be controllers and views. From MVC point of view, in your app these will be the Model.
I suggest you to prefer Cocoa (Touch) Framework classes.

Comment: Thanks is a good choice, but like I said to Amar, "but if I want to have only one project? and also if I discover a bug I will resolve once and copy again the lib/framework to the others projects?"

Comment: In that tutorial are 2 aproaches: 1) the Header and Library Binary Files; this means that the project will stand alone. When you find a bug you'll go in that project, fix the bug, then copy the files (headers + .lib file) again; 2) Subprojects : This means that in your project you have access into that common project and modify the code; note that, if you have 2 projects which are using one common project, only one can open it. Both approaches are good, just use the one which suits you. For further details, please read the tutorial.

Comment: I will try the second approach but probably your answer will be chosen thanks

Answer (score 1):

I create many apps from a single workspace. I have created separate schemes/targets for each apps. I have separate resources/xib/plist/prefix/build files for each targets. In some places, particular target should execute a specific set of code. For this, I have added unique macros in the target'e prefix files.

Comment: Suresh, you can have project with sub-project right? so i have scheme from parent project that will start mainwindow from one sub-project, the problem is in parent project don't know or don't have that mainwindow in bundle. (see my edit please)