# How to let multiple projects use a shared 'engine' module under xcode/git environment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git

I'm working on several personal ios apps using xcode/git to dev and manage my projects. Now as time goes on, lots of classes have appeared to be reusable so I would like to build a personal 'engine' out of them.

Ideally, I would make a separate repository in my git account for this engine, and make all other projects refer to the engine by importing header files and linking compiled modules, i.e not caring about engine implementation.

What would be a reasonable way to do this? My problems are essentially:

1. How to organize repositories on both remote and local machine? Let's say there are project A, B and engine E. Both A & B wants to take advantage of using E.
2. How to configure A & B so that in linking stage, compiled modules from E are available to the projects?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it essential to use the compiled module for E? If only you are using this code, you can use cocoapod to create and manage the engine module. For more information see http://cocoapods.org

Comment: We were using the cocoapod approach and decided it was a bad idea. The problem is you often find yourself needing to change library (engine) code while debugging a host app. So, you need to go back to the library repo, change the code, recompile the pod, then update the host every time you make a change. Takes forever! We're going to try embedded frameworks stored in git submodules. (Haven't done it yet, so I can't recommend it, per se, but it seems promising)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reuse Swift code in other projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518077/how-to-reuse-swift-code-in-other-projects)

Answer (score 0):

If all projects have deployment target greater than or equal to iOS 8.0 you can setup your engine as a framework (watch this [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=416) if you don't know how to set it up). Otherwise a [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081627/how-to-have-one-core-in-several-applications/23081875#23081875) is another good choice.